# Raspberry Pi program that interfaces with I/O (HID, SPI, GPIO)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, spi, interrupt-handling

I am working on a project using a Raspberry Pi where I need to create a GUI that can interface with the various peripherals.  Specifically the program needs to:

-read the position data from a touchscreen, mouse, or other HID

-perform some math on on the position data

-store the data in a FIFO buffer

-output that data over the SPI port at a fixed frame rate

I have an electronics background, with some experience writing firmware for microcontrollers, but I'm a relative novice when it comes to this kind of stuff.  I have done some research, and it looks like the mouse/touchcreen data is available by reading a file in the /dev/input directory, and I assume you can access the SPI port by reading or writing to some file in the /dev directory.  (I am currently running Raspbian)

My initial thoughts were to write a simple C program that a) reads the touchscreen data file and stores it into a preallocated buffer in memory and b) writes the data that next in line to the SPI data file in order to write it out to the SPI port.  Part (a) would fire off either on a timer interrupt and poll the touchcreen data to see if it's new, or fire off from a "new data" interrupt.  Part (b), the SPI part of the program, would fire off at a fixed rate, probably from a timer interrupt.

So my questions are:

-Is it even possible (or easy) to access interrupts or system timers from the user space?  I assume you would need to get hooks into the kernel somehow?

-If so, how would I make it so that my function runs whenever a interrupt or timer fires off?

-How easy is it to use the SPI DMA in user space?  Does anyone have any experience doing that?  I did a little research and it looks like you need to load a custom kernel driver, but I didn't know how tricky that would be.

-Is it possible to write out a parallel word on the GPIOs the way you would do it on a microcontroller (ie all at once by writing the word to the port's output register)?

I know there are plenty of higher level programming languages and wrappers that allow you to talk to the perepherals, but I'm a little hesitant doing it that way since the timing seems pretty tight.  I need to output (3) 16-bit words per frame at ~1k frames per second.  At 500kHz SPI bitrate, each frame is 96 us long, and at 1k frames per second, each period is 1ms.  This is why SPI DMA, or even writing the data out as a parallel word would be a lot easier in terms of timing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `/dev/mem` (or `/dev/kmem`) with `mmap()` are great for writing proof-of-concept code in userspace.  You eventually want to make a kernel driver, but you can get most of the debugging done in a much lower-pain way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Do you know of any good tutorials or references for writing kernel drivers or for writing PoC code using /dev/mem with mmap()?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this site is not a *forum*, and it is a **bad place** for "where to start" ("How would you recommend implementing this program?") requests. We want a specific **question**, which can be **answered**, not *discussed*.

Comment: My bad, I must have misunderstood.  Well, if you disregard the line "How would you recommend implementing this program?", there are several specific questions within my original post that should lead to specific answers.  I will edit the post to get rid of discussion-style, open ended questions.

Comment: There are already userspace APIs to do what you want without trying to do impossible things like perform DMA or handle interrupts from userspace.  There should be no reason to use **/dev/mem** either.  The **input event** subsystem you mention can be read to get touchscreen input; study **Documentation/input/input.rst**.  The **spidev** device can be used to perform I/O by the SPI master controller; study **Documentation/spi/spidev**.  Whether you can get everything to work fast enough is probably the real issue.